# Is there an easy way to export data from Drupal 7 to wordpress, non critical data, loosing data is fine

Tags: import, export

Is there a way to do a simple export/import as a CSV file from Drupal 7 to Wordpress?

Data is not critical, if I get the bulk of it it's ok, I don't care.

Drupal site has one single database shared by CIVI and core.

And wordpress is also sharing same database.

Comment: Do you mean CiviCRM data  - or drupal data like pages & users.

Comment: Only CIVICRM data, nothing connected to Drupal

Comment: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-cms/ is the docs you're looking for